# Exporting multiple files

Tags: export

I used Mathematica to export plots of *NM* measurements with this code:

```
Do[Export["Plot" <> ToString[i] <> ".pdf", Plottable[[i]], "PDF"], {i, NM}];
```

It does what it should do and I found this solution often on the Internet.
On the other hand, I often read that one should avoid loops.

Is there a better (more elegant) solution? (I am not looking for another solution that just works.)

Comment: "Avoid" is a rather strong word here. If your output is expected to be indexed, as in this case, then certainly you should employ a loop. `Do[]` is in fact eminently suitable.

Comment: Nevertheless, `Scan[]` is sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, in this case I think `Do` is acceptable.

However, an arguably more elegant way of approaching the task, where you don't need to specify the number of elements in `plottable`, is with [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html).

```
MapIndexed[Export["Plot" <> ToString @@ #2 <> ".pdf", #1, "PDF"] &, plottable]
```

Unlike `Do` this returns a list of the outputs of `Export`, i.e. the names of the written files, which of course can be suppressed using `;`.